# Detect if live tiles are enabled while application is in foreground

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, live-tile

Can I detect if live tile is enabled/disabled for a Windows 8/8.1 Store application when I am running the application/in foreground?

Comment: Are you asking whether or not the user has disabled the live tile setting for your app?  What would you do differently if you knew?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you're asking whether you can detect if the user has turned a live tile off on the Start screen? If so, then you want to check the [TileUpdater.Setting property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdater.setting.aspx) (you get the TileUpdater from [TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdatemanager.createtileupdaterforapplication.aspx) or [CreateTileUpdaterForSecondaryTile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdatemanager.createtileupdaterforsecondarytile.aspx)).

The Setting property gives you a [NotificationSetting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.notificationsetting.aspx) value which will tell you if it's enabled or disabled for various reasons.